# MVC Razor Ajax call from button click

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm struggling to get a button click to invoke an Ajax function which then posts to a controller action. Cannot even get a simple message to work (nothing happens when button is clicked). Clearly, I'm missing something fundamental. What is it?

The Ajax script in my Razor form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#UseShipAddr').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@(Url.Action("UseShippingAddress", "Checkout"))",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: 50 },
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The button that I want to use to invoke the Ajax function:

```
<input type="button" value="Use Shipping Address" id="UseShipAddr" />
```

The action in CheckoutController:

```
// Ajax POST: /Checkout/UseShippingAddress/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UseShippingAddress(int id)
        {            
            return Content("It worked!");
        }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Check your browser console for any js errors which might be the cause for your js code to not work as expected.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Is jquery loaded? Is the script at the bottom of the page, or wrapped in `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#UseShipAddr').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "Checkout/UseShippingAddress",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: 50 },
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```