# How to get particular row data when click on that particular row button using ASP .NET Core MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-core

I have two Controllers and their views. The first controller is the applicant controller, In this applicant controller, I have the "add applicant" form. This form link is given to the Second controller(vacancycontroller) view. Now I want to get data on the vacancy positions when I click on the button. Is this possible?

```
public class Application : IVacancy, IStage
{
   
    [Key]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
  
 

    [Required]
    [MinLength(2)]
    [MaxLength(50)]       
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
   
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
   
    public string Address { get; set; }
   
    public int? Experience { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    
    public string Resume { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vacancy")]
    public int? VacancyId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Stage")]
    public int? StageId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("VacancyId")] 
    public virtual Vacancy Vacancy { get; set; }
}
```

This is my application entity.

```
public  interface IVacancy
{
    public int? VacancyId { get; set; }
    public Vacancy Vacancy { get; set; }
}

[Table("vacancy")]
public class Vacancy  
{   
    [Key]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(2)]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Position { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Skills { get; set; }
}
```

And this is vacancy entity.

When I open the vacancy page and click on add applicant, In add applicant form, VaacancyId Text box fills with the Position of that particular row.[This is vacancy page img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCo3D.png)

Comment: i think you can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301192/mvc-razor-ajax-call-from-button-click

But Please post View code to give a correct answer